# Convert Entire Dataframe to a column and insert into a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-scrubbing

Currently my data frame looks something like this

```
A B C D
1 2 2 3
4 5 5 6
```

I want some thing like this

```
Insert_date  Bulk_load
09-09-2022   [[A, B,C,D],
             [1,2,2,3],
             [4,5,5,6]]
10-09-2022   [[Q,Z,R,F], (This is an example for dataframe with new values.)
             [1,2,2,3],
             [4,5,5,6]]
```

Has any one tried to implement this before?

Comment: why not use `df.to_dict()` or `df.to_json()` for your Bulk_load column

Comment: We explicitly wanted to create a string data type

Comment: ok, so `df.to_string()`

Comment: Your expected output is not in a format that makes any sense... Is `Bulk_load` a column with... Is that a list of strings? A list of lists of strings? A weirdly formatted string? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion output is a list of strings. Bulk_load should have nested list of string_list.  Each row should be string list including the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5, 6]]
```

```
bulk_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Insert_date', 'Bulk_load']).set_index('Insert_date')
bulk_df.loc['09-09-2022', 'Bulk_load'] = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                              Bulk_load
Insert_date
09-09-2022   [[A, B, C, D], [1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This works but when I am creating a data frame. I am getting 1 row for each list. Above code gives me 3 rows but I need only 1 row and in bulk_load column entire nested list should be present,

Comment: Please edit your question to show *exactly* what the contents of each cell should look like - with proper python formatting. `"A", "B","C","D"...` doesn't mean anything in python without proper brackets, newlines, etc...

Comment: I have updated the question now.